# Debugging sequence of forms in C#

Tags: c#

Hi friends my question is how can I determine the sequence of debugging.I mean I have two forms and I want to start with `Form1` but when ı run my program, firstly `Form2` is running.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Set form1 to startup form at Program.cs ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside form1?

Answer (score 1):

In a Visual Studio solution you can view the program.cs file in the startup project to see which form is loaded first if there are several present.

Comment: Thanks friends in Program.cs I changed Application.Run(new Form2()); to Application.Run(new Form1()); It solved my problem thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Ans:

- Open Program.cs from solution Explorer
- Change code From

  ```
      Application.Run(new Form1());  //// Chage Form1 To the "New Form 2" 
      Application.Run(new Form2());  //// Chaged starting Point of Application
  ```